# command line for these metadata ,and prorgam

Tags: ffmpeg, command, metadata, line

I have these information about video

```
Metadata:
Major_brand :mp42
Minor_version:0
Compatible_brands:mp42isom
Duration:00:00:42.46 , start:0.000000, bitrate :1564 kb/s 
Stream #0:0(und):video :h264(avc1/0×31637661),yuv420p(tv,btg470bg/btg470bg/smpte170m) , 640×352 , 1464 kb/s , 28.41 fps , 30 tbr , 90 k tbn , 180k tbt (default)

Metadata :
Rotate    :90
Vendor_id :[0][0][0][0]

Side data : 
Displaymatrix :rotation of -90.00 degrees

Stream #0:1(und) : Audio : aac(mp4a / 0×6134706D) , 48000 Hz ,stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)

Vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]
```

---

Please,

Can you tel me, what program this video was made from ??

And, How can I make a video with above features?

Comment: Thnx for ur help to any one who can help me for thses

Comment: The metadata do not indicate what program this video was made from.